# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed when using a dataset with tuples

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to create my own transformer with tensorflow and of course I want to train it. For the purpuse I use dataset to handle my data. The data is created by a code snippet from the tensorflow dataset.from_tensor_slices() method documentation article. Nevertheless, tensorflow is giving me the following error when I call the fit() method:

> "**OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.**"

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

batched_features = tf.constant([[[1, 3], [2, 3]],
                                [[2, 1], [1, 2]],
                                [[3, 3], [3, 2]]], shape=(3, 2, 2))
batched_labels = tf.constant([['A', 'A'],
                              ['B', 'B'],
                              ['A', 'B']], shape=(3, 2, 1))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((batched_features, batched_labels))
dataset = dataset.batch(1)
for element in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
  print(element)

class MyTransformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def call(self, inputs, training):
        print(type(inputs))
        feature, lable = inputs
        return feature

model = MyTransformer()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),
                       tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()])

model.fit(train_data, batch_size = 1, epochs = 1)
```

The code is reduced significantly just for the purpuse of reproducing the issue.

I've tried passing the data as dictionary instead of tuple and couple more things but nothing worked. It seems that I am missing something.

Comment: Have you find a solution yet? I am having the same problem :(

Comment: @Franciska Yeah, you need to implement your own trainer from scratch. However, what is the purpose of the fit method if you do that? I think there is a disconnection between what the documentation says and what it is actually happening. I've opened an issue to Tensorflow in their GitHub repo but the quality of the conversation was very poor. This led me to move to PyTorch. PyTorch is a bit more straightforward and you can count on the documentation. At least, this is my opinion for now. Time will tell if my decision was right.